# Asp RadioButtonList rendering differently in same browser on different sites

Tags: asp.net, radiobuttonlist

IE11 is rendering a RadioButtonList differently depending on which site is serving it.
Both sites use IIS7 and Asp.Net 4.0.

The RadioButtonList html is as follows:

```
<div style="font-size:larger; font-weight:bold; text-decoration: underline; text-align:center">
        Please rate the quality of service provided by your Project Manager/Service Delivery Team in delivering your order
</div>
<p></p>
<div style="width:100%; margin-left:120px">
        <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server" RepeatDirection="vertical" CssClass="SurveyRadioButtonList" RepeatLayout="Table">
            <asp:ListItem Text="Unacceptable" Value="Unacceptable"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="Poor" Value="Poor"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="Fair" Value="Fair"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="Good" Value="Good"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="Excellent" Value="Excellent"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="Exceeds Expectations" Value="Exceeds Expectations"></asp:ListItem>
        </asp:RadioButtonList>
</div>
```

The related css is as follows:

```
.SurveyRadioButtonList label
{    
  margin-top: -3px;
}
.SurveyRadioButtonList td
{    
 border:0; 
 padding:0; 
}
```

A screen image of how it's supposed to look, and indeed DOES on one of the 2 sites is as follows:
[Hmm.. not allowed to post image due to lack of reputation! Basically, the radio buttons and labels are nicely listed vertically underneath each other]

A screen image is how it looks when rendering from the other server is as follows:
[This image would have shown the radio buttons and labels spewed diagonally over towards the right, very messy, with nothing lining up. Somewhat as if the RepeatLayout="Table" isn't working at all]

Remember, both images come from the same browser (IE11, not in compatibility mode) running on the same PC (Win7), but from 2 different websites. Both websites are running windows, with both the sites hosted on IIS7 and ASP.Net 4.0.

Does anyone have any ideas? I have searched quite exhaustively without success.
Many thanks.
Bob

Comment: You could upload the image on flickr or any third party image sites and then add the link to your post

Comment: Are they patched the same? There are patches for browser definition updates since 4.x due to IE 10 and 11. Could one site not have the patch? That would change the rendered HTML. Also use the F12 developer tools to ensure that there isn't a JS error in the console view, as well as check the network tab to see if all the CSS and JS references are identical and loading correctly including the calls to the script handlers.